# TreeCellRenderer: applying different style of the node's text which is depending on the user object's type

Tags: java, swing, render, jtree

I have a tree with DefaultMutableTreeNodes only. I want to write a TreeCellRenderer that depends on the type of the contained user object. I tried to write a simple example (which doesn't work. That's why I ended up here). On the first level beyond the root node, the types of the user objects are either `AANodeUserObject`or `LocalAANodeUserObject`. Both should be rendered with directory icons even though there might be no child. The other feature of this renderer is, that it should render nodes with user object type `AANodeUserObject` in red color and bold when they are not "current" (in my example, this is always `true`). Here is my code:

```
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(final JTree tree, final Object value, final boolean sel, final boolean expanded, final boolean leaf, final int row, final boolean hasFocus)
    {
        super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, sel, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);
        // Precondition für Default TreeNode
        Object userObject = ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) value).getUserObject();
        if (userObject instanceof TestTree.AANodeUserObject || userObject instanceof TestTree.LocalAANodeUserObject)
        {
            if (expanded)
            {
                setIcon(openIcon);
            }
            else
            {
                setIcon(closedIcon);
            }
        }

        if (userObject instanceof TestTree.AANodeUserObject)
        {
            TestTree.AANodeUserObject aAnode = (TestTree.AANodeUserObject) userObject;
            if (!mVersionInfo.get(aAnode))
            {
                renderOutdatedAaNode();
            } else {
                renderDefault();
            }
        }  else {
            renderDefault();
        }
        return this;
    }

    private void renderDefault()
    {
        setTextNonSelectionColor(cColorBlack);
        setTextSelectionColor(cColorBlack);
        setFont(getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN));
    }

    private void renderOutdatedAaNode()
    {
        setTextNonSelectionColor(cColorRed);
        setTextSelectionColor(cColorRed);
        setFont(getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
    }
```

You can see the result on the attached picture[image: The resulting tree].

What irritates me is that the directory-icon-thing works fine, the text style doesn't: only the second node (Hashmap value is `false`) AANodeUserObject should be red and nothing else.
What am I doing wrong? Can somebody help?
Thanks!
Mathias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problems by calling `super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, sel, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus)` twice:

- The first time as first line of `getTreeCellRendererComponent()`. Without the call, `getFont(setFont())` to set the font style to bold will return a `NullPointerException`.
- The second time at the last line in the method to render the nodes properly.

There might be another solution but after many different tries, this has worked for me.

Comment: even if it works, it's a **hack** around a serious problem. Hacks tend to bite back in future, so don't. Instead, dig for the underlying problem and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Boolean isCurrent = false;
if (!isCurrent)
```

What do you want to do by this code?

Also you need to implement "else" for this "if":

```
if (userObject instanceof TestTree.AANodeUserObject)
{
    //...
}
```

Otherwise all your renderer components will be printed with red font.

Comment: You are right, in this example, all nodes with AANodeUserObjects will be rendered red. But why are the Leafs also red?!

Comment: Tree use one instance of renderer to draw all nodes. So if you once make renderer font red - it will be red always untill you decide to change it to another color.

Comment: Also I advise you not to use setText("<html><b>...</b></html>") to format value with html. You can simply use setFont(getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD)). Consider that in that case you should always set needed font in every call to renderer.

Comment: Have I answered your questions?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I updated the description of my problem. I tried to include all your suggestions in the new code.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are returning "`this`"?

You should create a variable in which you temporarily store the returned value of the method from the super class which you are calling at the beginning. And then you have to modify this reference and return it at the end. Then you would not have any problems!

Comment: most probably s/he is extending DefaultTreeCellRenderer which is-a JLabel, so returning this is just fine